# ¿Cómo itero vectores que se generan a partir de cierta cantidad de elementos?

Tags: c++, string, map, vectores, c++17

En este ejercicio me pidieron recibir los datos de los vehículos de una empresa de transporte (solo hay una).

El input se coloca de la siguiente manera:

```
# Nombre de la empresa
El rapido
# Número de vehículos que posee
3
# Placa del primer vehículo
AAA111
# Modelo del primer vehículo
Kia
# Año del primer vehículo
2013
# Placa del segundo vehículo
BBB999
# Modelo del segundo vehículo
Toyota
# Año del segundo vehículo
2018
# Placa del tercer vehículo
CCC555
# Modelo del tercer vehículo
Nissan
# Año del tercer vehículo
2017
```

A partir de esto, debo recibir los datos y generar el siguiente output:

```
Vehiculo [1] Placa: AAA111, Modelo: Kia, Anio: 2013
Vehiculo [2] Placa: BBB999, Modelo: Toyota, Anio: 2018
Vehiculo [3] Placa: CCC555, Modelo: Nissan, Anio: 2017
```

Hasta ahora, tengo este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using entrada_t = std::vector<std::string>;
    using vehiculos_t = std::map<std::vector<std::string>, entrada_t>;

    std::string Empresa;
    vehiculos_t vehiculos;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, Empresa))
    {
        // Se ha leido una empresa, leemos cuantos vehículos tiene
        unsigned cantidadVehiculos;
        std::cin >> cantidadVehiculos;
        std::cin.ignore(1);
        // Creamos la entrada en vehiculos
        auto [iterador, b] = vechiculos.insert({Empresa, vehiculos_t(cantidadVehiculos)});

        // Leemos los datos de los vehículos
        for (int indice = 0; indice != 3; ++indice)
        {
            std::string Placa;
            std::getline(std::cin, iterador->first[indice]);
        std::string Modelo;
            std::getline(std::cin, iterador->second[indice]);
            std::string Anio;
            std::getline(std::cin, iterador->third[indice]);
        }
    }

    // Mostramos los datos
    for (const auto &[k, v] : vehiculos)
    {
        for (int i=0; i != cantidadVehiculos; i++) {
        std::cout << "Vehiculo [" << i << "] "<< "Placa: " << v[0] << ", Modelo: " << v[1] << ", Anio: " << v[2] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, este no retorna el resultado, ¿entonces cómo guardo los tres datos de cada vehículo según la cantidad de vehículos que posea la empresa? En todo caso, ¿qué errores estoy cometiendo al iterar? Sería de mucha ayuda si me respondieran, gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta proveyendo un [ejemplo _mínimo_ reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).